# cross-gcc doesn't search for target as and ld in path?

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling

I've successfully built a couple of cross-gcc compilers, hosted on OSX Lion and targeting both i386-pc-solaris2.10 and x86_64-linux-gnu.
I have 2.22 binutils for those target installed under $BINUTILSROOT and $BINUTILSROOT/bin in my PATH. Reading http://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html, in particular

> --with-as=pathname
>   Specify that the compiler should use the assembler pointed to by pathname, rather than the one found by the standard rules to find an assembler, which are:
>
> - Unless GCC is being built with a cross compiler, check the libexec/gcc/target/version directory. libexec defaults to exec-prefix/libexec; exec-prefix defaults to prefix, which defaults to /usr/local unless overridden by the --prefix=pathname switch described above. target is the target system triple, such as `sparc-sun-solaris2.7', and version denotes the GCC version, such as 3.0.
> - If the target system is the same that you are building on, check operating system specific directories (e.g. /usr/ccs/bin on Sun Solaris 2).
> - Check in the PATH for a tool whose name is prefixed by the target system triple.
> - Check in the PATH for a tool whose name is not prefixed by the target system triple, if the host and target system triple are the same (in other words, we use a host tool if it can be used for the target as well).

I thought my -gcc (configured with *--with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld*) would have picked up respectively i386-pc-solaris2.10-as and x86_64-linux-gnu-as (and corresponding -ld) because they are in $BINUTILSROOT/bin which is in the PATH and so the 3rd bullet from the above list should apply.
But this doesn't seem to work, and I've confirmed with dtrace that -gcc doesn't search for -as and -ld in the PATH. 
The only solution I've found to be working is to also fully specify as and ld adding

> --with-as=$BINUTILSROOT/bin/-as --with-ld=$BINUTILSROOT/bin/-ld

when configuring gcc.

Am I misinterpreting gcc docs, or this is the only way to have cross-compilation working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinarily you'd install a cross-compiler in the same directory as your cross-binutils. If you do that it'll Just Work.

If you're not installing the compiler into the same directory because you want to "stage" it for building a package, then you should configure with the `--prefix` of the final installed location (in which the binutils should already be present), and then install with

```
make DESTDIR=/path/to/staging/dir install
```

to override the prefix setting. You'd then copy those files into the true prefix (presumably as part of a package install) before you use them.

If you don't want to install in the same directory for another reason then you have to specify the path as you've discovered. There are other ways to make it work, but --with-as is the intended solution. If you really don't like that solution, then you can do

```
make configure-gcc
ln -s $BINUTILSROOT/bin/as gcc/as
ln -s $BINUTILSROOT/bin/ld gcc/ld
```

That will make the build work (IIRC), but the final installed compiler will still look in the standard places. In fact, this works because, during build only, the gcc directory *is* one of the standard places.

The reason for all this is that it doesn't use "x86_64-linux-gnu-as": it actually uses "prefix/x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/as" and if that doesn't exist it looks in the other standard places for "as", and typically finds the host "/usr/bin/as" which doesn't work well (and leads to very confusing error messages).